# Error Message: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps is denied

Tags: windows-store, xaf, desktop-bridge

I distributed my xaf Winforms+Desktop Bridge app to myself via the Windows Store.

[following this blog](http://blog.delegate.at/2018/04/15/how-to-use-the-desktop-bridge-to-create-an-appx-package-for-xaf.html)

From the blog, I want to pre-generate the ModelAssembly.dll, Model.Cache.xafml and ModulesVersionInfo file and package them to go in the output directory.

These files are generated by XAF if they don't already exist.

Where the output directory is given by

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(GetType().Assembly.Location)
```

When I install and run my app from the store. I get this error message.

```
Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\JobTalk.JobTalk_1.0.19.0_x64__8kpaqbvntb9aj\SBD.JobTalk.Workflow.Win10\ModelAssembly.dll' is denied.
```

In the code I tried looking form Path.GetRelativePath  but it is not available in Framework 4.7.2

[image: looking for path.getrelativepath]

Comment: Could you please describe your scenario why you want to get this dll?

Comment: I want to be able to distribute my Dev Express xaf applications using the store.
The scenario is described in detail in the linked post.

Comment: This may be relevant https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T621515/how-to-generate-and-deploy-the-modelassembly-dll-at-build-time-packaging-for-desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, UWP app doesn't allow to access files via absolute path. Because UWP apps run in sandbox and have very limited access to the files out of the app container. In most scenarios, the UWP app can directly access only their install folder and their application data folder. Since the converted app also is a UWP app, so your app need to follow this rule.

Please check the [Prepare to package a desktop application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare). The document has mentions some scenarios that is related to your question.

> Your application writes to the AppData folder or to the registry with the intention of sharing data with another app. After conversion, AppData is redirected to the local app data store, which is a private store for each UWP app.
>
> Your application writes to the install directory for your app. For example, your application writes to a log file that you put in the same directory as your exe. This isn't supported, so you'll need to find another location, like the local app data store.

Here, there's a special scenario that you could access files via files absolute path. It's a restricted capability called as **broadFileSystemAccess**. Once you add the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability, you could use the APIs in the [Windows.Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR227346) namespace to get all files that the user has access to. Please read [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations) for more information.

Please note that the document has explained:

> If you submit an app to the Store that declares this capability, you will need to supply additional descriptions of why your app needs this capability, and how it intends to use it.

Comment: I aren't using absolute paths. I updated the question to show the paths I use.

Comment: @KirstenGreed `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\...` is absolute path.

Comment: @KirstenGreed First, please tell me what you want to do from this path?

Comment: I updated the question again. Hopefully it is clearer.

Comment: @KirstenGreed As I said in my above reply, you need to change the output directory. For example, the local folder.  `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`

Comment: I forgot to set the file links in the project to "Copy if newer"

Answer (score 0):

Xavier's answer explains what was going wrong.  The reason it happened on my project was that I missed the step of marking the linked files as "Copy if newer"